# Indexing in an array with two values

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

For same values of `Node.clus`, how can I retrieve the highest `Node.E` with its index?

Example: If `Node.clus==1`, there are `[(2,0.499773),(3,0.5) (15,0.499706)]`. 
i.e (Node.id,Node.E)

It should return `id = 3` and `E=0.5`;

i.e If `Node.clus==1`, 0.5 is highest and 3 is the index

[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the maximal value than [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) are your friends:

```
mx = accumarray(vertcat(Node.clus), vertcat(Node.E), [], @max);
```

Getting the index is a bit more tricky